Can I bring candles on a European flight?
I am travelling with Ryanair between two cities in Europe, and I would like to bring some candles along (yes, it's Christmas). They are solid, in glass jars, and 122 grams each (therefore above the 100 ml rule that applies to liquids). I only have my backpack (hand luggage), which I will take onboard with me. Do you think it will be fine? I found some contrasting info online, and I was wondering if someone has experience.

You might know this but for other people reading this: 122g of anything are not necessarily above 100ml, although I think it would usually be the case for candles, given the density of paraffin wax or beeswax.

@Relaxed: it would be definitely interesting to have a chat with density of soy wax at the security. unlikely to happen though. i somehow fail to see me telling the security that 122g of was are not 100ml because of some density thing ;-)

I think the rule is that the volume should be stated explicitly. If all you have is a weight in grams then that could be a problem. On the other hand, it should be possible to get on board with container with a weight > 100g but a volume < 100 mL as long as both are mentioned on the label.

smaller candles have caused me a problem in the past because there is a wick and a little metal disk at the bottom of the candle to hold it down and together these look quite bomby on an xray. But once someone saw them, they were permitted.

You may have more luck if you take the candles out of the glass jars. Wax inside jars might look suspicious, but empty glass jars are perfectly fine, and solid candles without jars are also perfectly fine. You can re-assemble them after you land.

Four candles would be allowed, although you might have to check them in if they were too long.

The 100 ml rule applies to liquids, aerosols and gels. Since your candles are solid, you should be fine.
See also: Solid Candles on the official TSA page (I know you're traveling in the EU, not the US, but the rules are largely identical)

that's the should be part that makes me worried. it would be a pity to just throw away 40€ worth of candles. maybe i'll call the airport infoline if there is any, just to make sure? would they know?

@gbt I think you should read that "you should be fine" as "yes, you're fine". I don't see why they would be forbidden. They don't appear in the list of forbidden objects: https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-us/articles/12890928594705-What-items-are-prohibited-on-board-and-in-Check-in-Bags

@gbt There's always some uncertainty because the people interpreting the rules are human and make stupid calls sometimes: I've had a 125 ml tin of anchovies confiscated because they were tinned in oil and oil is a liquid.

@xtropicalsoothing thanks for the reference!

@lambshaanxy alright, i guess i will know for sure once i am past the security.

@gbt Looking forward to hearing how you got on!

@lambshaanxy I remember signs all over Lisbon airport warning not to take sardine tins as cabin luggage. The rationale for the interpretation is questionable, just like that for the rule itself, but this interpretation may not be as arbitrary as it seems.

"The rules are largely identical" - this unfortunate assumption got the contents of my toolbag confiscated in the UK, even though all tools were TSA acceptable :( Had a little adjustable wrench that I'll really miss.

@Relaxed In my case I love the rule, the smell of tinned anchovies or sardines brings me to vomit :D

@YanickSalzmann Do you smell it on tins?

@Relaxed I've seen them in the duty-free in Lisbon airport though. The security rule on liquids (100ml and total < 1litre) should actually apply to all liquids regardless of packaging, however Portugal has an exception  from the rule  allowing up to 150g of canned fish per container (and apparently no limit on cans)- they note it only applies to domestic airports so if you have a connecting flight that originates outside Portugal you could have problems.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Maybe that's what the signs were about? I don't recall the details but they definitely warn you against taking tins in cabin luggage. On the other hand, you can typically buy whatever you want in the duty-free area, even 1L bottles of alcohol, this was about things you bring with you through security.

@Relaxed The link (in Portuguese) states the new EU rule came into force in 2006 but it doesn't say when the exception came into force. It's possible there was a decade or more when it was not allowed.

@lambshaanxy Why do you think the rule was enforced incorrectly? Based on my reading of the EU restrictions on liquids they were right.

I have done this in the past. As @lambshaanxy explained, there is no reason the 100 ml rule would apply to candles but since glass jars look like something that might contain a liquid, I once actually had to unpack my whole bag to allow for closer inspection. Once the security staff was satisfied these were indeed candles, they sent me on my way with my candles.

alright, tomorrow we will know! thanks for sharing.

@gbt So, what happened?
